# Bing maps REST API does not work

Tags: bing-maps

I am trying to show routes using BING maps REST service , but the map image with routes does not show up sometimes (shows blank map) , but after refreshing the html page it shows up.
I have contructed below URL
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Road/Routes?wp.0=300%20Albemarle%20Road,,,Charleston,29407-7593&wp.1=1000%20Fort%20Johnson%20Road,,,Charleston,29412-8898&wp.2=1525%20Avenue%20B%20South,,,North%20Charleston,29405-2328&mapVersion=v1&mapSize=800,600&zoomLevel=10&key="my bing map key"

Answer (score 1):

I've taken a look at this. I was able to reproduce the error with your URL. I tried modifying it by removing the extra comma's and the removing the last part of the zip codes (zip+4) since those are not supported. After doing that I was still able to reproduce this issue, but much less frequently. I suspect that there may be a couple servers that are out of sync on Bing Maps side, thus the inconsistency. I'll notify the engineering team so they can look into this.

Comment: Thanks a ton , I also found that below URL return "Serevice Unavailable" many times and even though they return 200/OK status but does not return any data. This behavior is consistent in IE11 and works much better in chrome and firefox.

Comment: 1)Trip Route - https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes?wp.0=9000%20Ashford%20dunwoody%20rd,%20atlanta%20,%20georgia%20,%2030338&wp.1=universal%20studios%20,%20florida&routePathOutput=Points&output=json&jsonp=RouteCallback&key=

Comment: 2) Trip Route Image - https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Road/Routes?wp.0=9000%20Ashford%20dunwoody%20rd,%20atlanta%20,%20georgia%20,%2030338&wp.1=universal%20studios%20,%20florida&mapVersion=v1&mapSize=800,600&zoomLevel=10&key=

Comment: 3) Location Image - -  https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/9000%20Ashford%20dunwoody%20rd,%20atlanta%20,%20georgia%20,%2030338?output=json&jsonp=GeocodeCallback&key=

Comment: does following things affects the output 1) Calling https vs http service 2) Bing map key is not enterprise key , Also I found that the error more prominent in IE11 whereas in chrome it works much better , any thougts ?

Comment: Looking into this it appears that there is an extremely high volume of basic accounts making a lot of requests. As such the service is rate limiting requests to ensure that Enterprise keys are not affected by this usage. If you look at the header of a response you will see a flag that indicates that the request was rate limited. This is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701703.aspx